# How to suspend a thread execution in jsr223 sampler

Tags: apache, jmeter

Im using the following code to stop a thread  using jsr223 sampler on a specific condition.
Thread group.stop(Thread.currentThread.getname())
But the jmeter engine is ignoring the above condition and proceeding.
Can some one pls help on the right function.

Regards
Shankar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call on the SampleResult

> SampleResult.setStopThread(true)

See:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler
- https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setStopThread-boolean-

Comment: UBIK Load PACK, That didnot work as well .Here is a sample codedef x =1;
if(x>1)
{
 log.info("retaining thread ");
 
}
else
{
 log.info("Suspending thread ");
   SampleResult.setStopThread(true);
 }
log.info("statement after condition");
2018-08-21 11:09:23,694 INFO o.a.j.p.j.s.JSR223Sampler: Suspending thread 
2018-08-21 11:09:23,695 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Stopping: Thread Group 1-1
2018-08-21 11:09:23,695 WARN o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Sampler is not Interruptible: JSR223 Sampler
2018-08-21 11:09:23,696 INFO o.a.j.p.j.s.JSR223Sampler: statement after condition

Comment: The thread is not immediately stopped in sampler but after it has completed it. I am sure about it. you cannot stop immediately a thread in java. You accepted the wrong answer IMO. You should know that we are commiters of JMeter.

Comment: Ya that is true ..as I check the sampler gets suspended after the current iteration.. thanks for Ur note :)

Answer (score 0):

The correct function would be

[`ThreadGroup.stopThread(java.lang.String threadName, boolean now)`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/ThreadGroup.html#stopThread-java.lang.String-boolean-)

Also be aware that [JMeterThread](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterThread.html) is not the same as [JVM Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html), i.e. they have different "names".

So you need to amend your code to look something like:

```
ctx.getThreadGroup().stopThread(ctx.getThread().getThreadName(),true)
```

where `ctx` is a shorthand for [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html)

You can also check out [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter) to learn what else could be done using Groovy scripting.

Comment: Hi Dmitry
Thanks for posting the syntax..the function is returning true.However the lines after this statement are still getting executed. So is there something else I need to do here.

Comment: JSR223 Sampler itself is not interruptable, the lines will be still executed by Groovy scripting engine. However if you have any other samplers below the JSR223 sampler - they will not be executed as the thread will be stopped.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri..but it s kind of strange that I cant suspend a thread in jsr 223..thanks again for your quick response